# Numericupdown does not display its value

Tags: winforms, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, numericupdown

### Background:

I have a numericupdown and its 'Value' property is bound to an object's property (a Decimal, of course). The object's class implements INotifyPropertyChanged and a propertychanged event is raised when the property changes its value, the binding is set to updatemode.OnPropertyChanged.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource myClassbindingSource;
```

In my Form's OnLoad, I have the following:

```
myClassbindingSource.Add( MyObject1 ); //(MyObject1 is an instance of MyClass)
base.OnLoad( e );
```

the auto-generated binding (after I changed its DataBinding's advanced property 'Data Source Update Mode' to 'OnPropertyChanged'):

```
this.NumericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding(
    "Value", this.myClassBindingSource, "MyProperty", true, 
    System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

My Class:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private Decimal myValue;

    public Decimal MyProperty{
    get { return myvalue; }
    set { 
        myvalue = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged( "MyProperty" );
    }

    ...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged( String info ) {
      var pceHandler = PropertyChanged;
      var pceArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs( info );
      if( pceHandler != null )
        pceHandler( this, pceArgs );
    }
}
```

### Problem:

Now, when the object's property changes from other parts of the code,  the NumericUpdown is not displaying its new value.

When I debug my code I can see that, when the property changes, the PropertyChanged event fires and the 'Value' property of my NUD gets the proper value, but the 'Text' property has its default "0.000" value.

There are other controls whos bindings work fine, e.g. checkboxes vs Booleans, labels vs strings. But not my NUD bound to a Decimal.

### Question:

How can I get the 'Text' property to update when the 'Value' property does, so the proper value is displayed?
Or rather, why does the 'Text' property NOT update?
Are there properties that can control how this is handled?

Comment: How are you binding? Show the code. Are you also binding to the text property? The text will display properly if things are setup correctly.

Comment: I believe I have set things up properly. When binding a bool to a checkbox that works fine (checkbox unchecks when the property is set to false). But setting up the numericupdown seems to require some extra treatment of some kind. Or that something is carefully thought about in other aspects around the binding/form/class. And that I need help to find out.

Comment: Your code works as pasted. No extra treatment should be required.  Create a new test project and verify. Then track down what you have done to break it in your app.

Comment: Actually, after restarting VS and my PC it works with nothing changed. So I was not wrong. John, thanks for your attention. If you want your more rep, paste your comment as answer and I'll mark it. Thanks.